# Targeting specific data with xpath or css via nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, css-selectors, nokogiri

I have Nokogiri parsing [this ESPN website](http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/bracketology). I want to search the page for the "North Carolina" and return the rank immediately left of it, which is "1" in this case. I will do this for all teams in my database, but one example should solve it for me.

I'm not sure if XPath or CSS selectors would be best. The span with the rank of North Carolina is

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/dl[1]/dd[1]/div[1]/span
```

How would I search for "North Carolina" and return its corresponding `span.rank`?

One potential wrinkle is, I'd need the syntax to account for any situation in which there are two teams on a single bracket line, e.g. "11 Georgia" versus "11 Rhode Island". The rank XPaths for those are slightly different than above, `span[1]` for the first team and `span[2]` for the second team:

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl[3]/dd[1]/div[2]/span[1]
//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl[3]/dd[1]/div[2]/span[2]
```

Comment: When asking about how to parse HTML, it's very important to provide a minimal example of the HTML in the question itself instead of a link the the entire page. Links rot then break, which, at that point, would make your question impossible to figure out. And, by providing a link you're expecting those helping you to load the page and search for the section you're talking about, wasting their time and yours since it delays getting an answer to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible XPath to get `span` element that corresponds to `a` element containing certain text :

```
//div[@class='team' and a='NORTH CAROLINA']/span
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. It seems to work across the board. One weird behavior is that when a= team that is in a play-in game (two matchups on a single line), it pulls in both seeds, like "1616". e.g. `//div[@class='team' and a='Georgia']/span` yields `"1111"`. I could trim that in my ruby code, using a conditional but thought I'd double check to see if there was a way to get around that in the xpath. Much thanks @har07, you've been very helpful!